# C++ MySql Connector - results from query going out of scope

Tags: c++, mysql-connector

I'm having a scoping issue with the results of a C++ mysql connector query execution.

In the code below the `ResultSet *` result is passed from another function, initially `NULL`; however, after performing the line `result = statement->executeQuery( query )`, result is no longer `NULL`.

There are no errors printed from the table either.

The issue arises when returning from that function. The `ResultSet *` result goes from being not `NULL` to being equal to `NULL`.

Clearly, there is some form of scoping on sql query results. Perhaps their function is returning a reference to a local variable ( Really not sure otherwise )?

How do I get around this scoping issue, so that classes/functions calling this function may do with the results as they please and mitigate the need to write a bunch of specialized functions in this wrapper? Furthermore, copies should be minimized - hence the use of pointers.

```
bool MySQLConnector::ExecuteQuery( std::string query, sql::ResultSet * result )
{

   //connection is a member variable and has been initialized
   sql::Statement * statement = connection->createStatement();

   try
   {
       result = statement->executeQuery( query );
   }
   catch( sql::SQLException &e )
   {
      //handle errors
   }

   delete statement;

   if( result == NULL )
   {
       printf( "Result is null File: %s Line %i\n", __FILE__, __LINE__ );
       return false;
   }
   else
   {
        printf("Result is not null File: %s Line %i\n", __FILE__, __LINE__ );
   }

   return true;
}
```

If I have a function `foo` that calls the function above with correct parameters. The `printf` stating that result is not null will print, but in `foo`, right after the execution of `ExecuteQuery`, the pointer passed into the function becomes `NULL`.

Comment: Don't forget that by default all function arguments are passed by *value*, meaning they are *copies*. Modifying (assigning to) a copy will not modify the original. Please learn more about *references* and how they can be used to solve your problem.

Comment: `executeQuery()` returns `NULL`. That's what's assigned to `result`. What gets passed into this function for the `result`, by value, is utterly and completely irrelevant. It gets overwritten by `executeQuery()`'s return value. The End.

Comment: Instead of trying to describe your code and what you're doing, please try to create a [mcve] to *show* us. *Where* is the pointer null? *Where* is it not supposed to be null? Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

**1. `result` is passed by value**

You pass `result` by value. Meaning that the function receives a copy of the pointer you pass when calling the method.

For example, if the code that calls `ExecuteQuery` look like this:

```
std::string query("SELECT ...");
sql::ResultSet *result = NULL;
ExecuteQuery(query, result);
```

Then `ExecuteQuery` cannot change the value of `result`, since it is COPIED into the method.
If you wish to change its value, you should pass a reference to result. You can do that by changing `ExecuteQuery` to:

```
bool MySQLConnector::ExecuteQuery( std::string query, sql::ResultSet *& result )
```

Then, `ExecuteQuery` manipulates the original pointer, rather than a copy.

**2. MySQL C++ API frees the `ResultSet` when the `Statement` is deleted**

Just like @nos pointed out, when you call `delete statement`, you also free the resources that hold the information for your `result`.

`result` will still have a valid value because it won't be aware of the deallocated memory, but if you access it, it might cause a segmentation fault.

The right way to handle this is to either:

- Copy the result
- OR
- Let the caller pass a statement object as well, and deallocate it after using the value from result.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand what you're saying now. Since I want the pointer I'm passing to store the contents of the address from the resulting query, you have to pass it by *& or **. This has corrected my issue. I've never really had a problem like this before, but I understand now. Per the second statement, I'll have to double check that. I left that code in and result is still valid and returning the correct information after statement has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool MySQLConnector::ExecuteQuery( std::string query, sql::ResultSet * result )
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^
```

Here, result is much like a local variable within a function, and it contains a *copy* of the variable of the caller.

When you assign to it within ExecuteQuery, it'll only affect the variable within the function, not the variable of the caller.

You can instead make it a reference, so it'll reference the variable of the caller like so:

```
bool MySQLConnector::ExecuteQuery( std::string query, sql::ResultSet *&result )
```

Another approach is to pass in a pointer to the variable (and as the variable is itself a pointer, you'll deal with a pointer to a pointer). This lets you also modify the pointer of the caller :

```
 bool MySQLConnector::ExecuteQuery( std::string query, sql::ResultSet **result ) {
 ...
     *result = statement->executeQuery( query );
```

This also requires modification to the caller, so it passes in a pointer to its local variable, e.g.

```
sql::ResultSet *rs;
c->ExecuteQuery("select ...", &rs);
```

Comment: `sql::ResultSet &*result` makes `result` a pointer to a reference, something which is not really possible. `sql::ResultSet *&result` is more correct. And please don't advice to do the old C-style pointer-as-a-way-to-*emulate*-pass-by-reference. C++ have proper references, use them.

Comment: binary01 likely meant \*& instead of &\*. However there's perhaps a bigger issue - the MySQL C++ API claims to be compatible with the JDBC API -  and that would mean  `ResultSet` is also closed when the associated `Statement` is closed/deleted - and the code of the OP deletes the statement.before the `ResultSet` is used.